# Correct squisshed bitmap on android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, android-image, android-bitmap

I have this wrong squashed Bitmap on android:

[image]

and I want to correct it as shown here:

[image]

possibly with Matrix object. How can I do that?

Comment: Pratically: I have to mantain the same rectangle (720,1280) but the content must be rotated (rows become columns, columns became rows).